# What exactly does the setting disk_optimization_strategy do?

Tags: cassandra, configuration

It offers the choice of SSD (default) or spinning.  What exactly does changing this setting to spinning do?

I.E. if one has Spinning disks with an SSD cache layer, what should be selected?
Or, if one uses a SAN (yea yea, I know - DON'T DO THAT), what is a better setting?

I'm thinking that maybe SSD would cause it to read/write smaller chunks of data, where spinning would queue up more to write at once to prevent excessive head movement?  But I cannot seem to find any help on the topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It impacts the size of the slabs in the file chunk cache and the buffer size of the file readers.  `ssd`s have a `disk_optimization_page_cross_chance` percent spill over before adding an extra page of size to the buffer when reading while `spinning` will always round up (ie a 5k record will use a 8k buffer when reading with spinning but with ssd it will be 4k).

I would recommend using the spinning if theres any spinning disks involved to get the most outta the seek when it does occur. The ssd cache layer will still improve that performance with hot data. Same with a SAN but... yeah... don't use a SAN. Its been tried by many and no ones enjoyed the experience. I don't expect you will notice too much or any of a performance difference with either setting but if you do please share on user list or here!

Comment: For spinning disks, there is always added one page. Check [SpinningDiskOptimizationStrategy](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/06209037ea56b5a2a49615a99f1542d6ea1b2947/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/io/util/SpinningDiskOptimizationStrategy.java#L29).
For ssd, the 4KB (one page) are added if the chance of crossing to the next page is more than a predefined value. Check [SsdDiskOptimizationStrategy](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/06209037ea56b5a2a49615a99f1542d6ea1b2947/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/io/util/SsdDiskOptimizationStrategy.java#L37).

Comment: You can also check [file_cache_round_up](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/801cb70ee811c956e987718a00695638d5bec1b6/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/config/Config.java#L282)

Comment: We will make this change.  I'm not expecting anything phenomenal, just looking for little things that hopefully will lead to an overall better place.

Comment: Yea... we are working on eliminating SAN - going full on bare-metal with SSDs and the lot.  Takes a while to get that through the "regular channels" if you know what I mean.  In the interim, we have to keep the boat afloat.